# Project Delete Button is disabled in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

Why the Delete Button for a VSTS Project is Disabled?

[image: VSTS with Project Delete Button Disabled]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This delete button isn't for the project, but for the Default team. In each project there is always at least one team. You can rename it if you want to, but you can't delete it.

You can delete the project from the Organisation -> Projects:

[image]